# Bad mask for IP 192.168.0.0 Cisco Packet Tracer

Tags: cisco, netmask, mask

I have to do next task: connect three LAN networks with Cisco packet tracer. I have to use net addresses 192.168.0.0/24; 192.168.10.0/24; 192.168.20.0/24. When I am trying to set router address 192.168.0.0 and mask 255.255.255.0 I have error message for bad mask. How to solve that issue?
My code:

```
Router>
Router>enable
Router#conf t
Router(config)#int fa 0/0
Router(config-if)#ip add 192.168.0.0 255.255.255.0
Bad mask /24 for address 192.168.0.0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple answer is `192.168.0.0` is not a valid ip address to use. It is a network Address. Please change your Ip address between `192.168.0.1-192.168.0.254`. Then It will be solved.

Network address is explained by techopedia as follows

> A network address is any logical or physical address that uniquely
>   distinguishes a network node or device over a computer or
>   telecommunications network. It is a numeric/symbolic number or address
>   that is assigned to any device that seeks access to or is part of a
>   network.

Host address is

> The physical address of a computer in a network. Host address is the
>   IP address of the machine.

Comment: But why I have that instructions in my task?

Comment: It says use it  as  anetwork address. Not a host address

Comment: Where I need to set those addresses?

Comment: It will refer your ip address range. That's all. `192.168.0.0/24 ` mean you are able to use 254 address for your host. Generally first address is network address and last one will be Broadcast address.

Comment: https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/7106/how-do-you-calculate-the-prefix-network-subnet-and-host-numbers

Comment: So I need to use host addresses from 192.168.0.1 to 192.168.0.255?

Comment: yes. You need to use as i explained. Especially You need to learn more about Subnet Masking